# Why is my footer element aligning to the right in desktop viewport but not in smaller viewports?

Tags: html, css

The footer at the bottom shifts to the right in desktop viewport but not in a smaller viewport. My goal is align it at the center for all viewports. I think the problem lies in the footer rule in the CSS file but i'm not sure.

I've included screenshots of how the codes look like in  desktop viewport and also mobile viewport.

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  font-family: "times new roman", calibri, cursive;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
}

.equip {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 0em;
  padding-top: 0em;
  margin-right: 3em;
  box-shadow: 1em 1em 2em powderblue;
}

h1 {
  padding-left: 30px;
  font-family: cursive, "times new roman";
}

h2 {
  margin-bottom: 130px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  font-family: "times new roman", cursive, calibri;
}

nav a {
  clear: both;
  margin-left: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

main {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 100px;
  background-color: powderblue;
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-left: 80px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 5px 8px 10px white;
  max-width: 890px;
}

p {
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}

ul li {
  color: black;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 130px;
}

footer {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="container">

    <p><img class="equip" src="images/Home Image1.jpg" alt="Durango Jewelry" width="260" height="195" title="Durango Jewelry"></p>

    <header>
      <h1>Durango Jewelry and Gem Shop</h1> <br>
      <h2>Distinguished wire-wrapped jewelry,pendants, and gems</h2>
    </header>

    <nav>
      <a href="Home.html">Home </a> &nbsp; &nbsp
      <a href="Classics.html">Classics </a> &nbsp; &nbsp
      <a href="Specials.html">Specials </a> &nbsp; &nbsp
      <a href="Gems.html">Gems</a> &nbsp; &nbsp
      <a href="Contact Me.html">Contact Me </a> &nbsp; &nbsp
    </nav>

    <main>
      <p>Durango Jewelry and Gem Shop pampers you with one-of-a-kind, high quality wire-wrapped pendants and gems. Our works of art are inspired by natural<br> geometries and the vast beauty of mother nature.<br></p>


      <p>The featured pendant provides these characteristics :<br><br>
        <ul>
          <li> <span style="color:red;">"Smoky Quartz"</span> gemstones, also called <span style="color:red;">"Soulmate Crystal"</span> </li>
          <li> gemstone is over 2 carats </li>
          <li> high quality silver alloy requires very little polishing </li>
        </ul><br>
      </p>

      <p>Come over to our store !</p>

    </main>

    <footer>
      <p style="color: white;font-size:0.8em;">Durango Jewelry Shop, <br> 101001 Main Street, <br> Durango CO |Established 1979 <br>
        <a style="color:powderblue" href="mailto:template.t@mailserver.com">Click Here to E-mail Us </a>
      </p>

    </footer>


  </div>

</body>
```

[Desktop viewport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zc0do.png)

[iPhone 4 viewport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/om0GL.png)

Comment: you need in center for desktop view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `<footer>` you have a `<p>` tag. And in your CSS you have `p { margin-left: 100px }`.

Answer (score 1):

by removing margin-left: 100px; in css of p tag    it works

```
     p  
      {
       padding-top: 20px;
       color: black;
       font-weight: bold;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have seen you code and found that your main section in not come in center your footer is already in center.
Because you have apply some left and right to the main section it is restrict to come in center, kindly replace you css with my suggested css and your issue will resolve.

Suggested css

```
main {
    background-color: powderblue;
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-shadow: 5px 8px 10px white;
    max-width: 890px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
```